# Couple of questions about rendering settings using python scripts

Tags: python, rendering, command-line

I am processing blender file using python script passed in -P cmd argument

I am new to blender so I am not familiar with all bpy
objects/properties. Can you help me with it?

1) How can I get current rendering tile and estimated time in cycles
rendering engine? I know there is render_stats handler, and I even
found function BlenderSession::get_progress in sources, but I am still
puzzled how can I get this info from python script.

2) How can I get list of cameras available?

3) How can I setup active camera for rendering?

4) How can I get/set number of samples when rendering?

Comment: Hi, this site works best when asking one question at a time. I would recommend searching this site to see if each question exists and then post them as new questions if they don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To know how to access properties in python just hover the mouse over the property in the UI and read the tooltip

```
# render tiles
scene.render.tile_x,
scene.render.tile_y,

#camera's list
cam_list = [cam for cam in bpy.data.object if object.type == 'CAMERA']

#set camera
scene.camera = cam_list[0]
#or
scene.camera = bpy.context.object
```